# Avoid duplication in API development with Play Framework

Tags: rest, model, playframework-2.0

I developed a REST API with Play 2.2.0. Some controllers expose GET methods, other expose POST methods with authentication etc...

I developed the client using Play as well but I have a problem. How can I avoid duplicating the model layer between both applications ?

- In the server application, I have a Model Country(code, name).
- In the client I am able to list countries and create new ones.

Currently, I have a class Country in both sides. When I get countries I deserialize them. The problem is that if I add a field in Country in the server, I have to maintain the client as well.

How can I share the Country entity between applications ?

PS : I don't want to create a dependency between the API and the client, as the client could have been developed with another language or framework

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not very specific to play framework but is more of a general question. You either create reusable representations of the data in your protocol (the actual data structures you send between your nodes) and get a tight coupling in representation and language. Many projects does it like this, since they know they will have the same platform throghout their architecture.

The other option is to duplicate all of or only the parts of parsing/generating that each part of the architecture needs, this way you get a looser coupling and can use any language in the different parts.

There are also some data protocols/tools that will have a representation in a protocol specific way and then can generate representations in various programming languages.

So as you see, it's all about pros and cons - neither solution is "the right way (tm)" to do this, you will have to think about your specific system/architecture and what pros are most valuable  and what cons are most costly to you.

Comment: I think I get what you mean. I was wondering if it is possible to do like people do with a top-down approach with SOAP : 1/ Write the schema of the data, 2/ Write the WSDL, 3/ Implement the operations in the server, 4/ Generate the data using CXF etc... in the client. Is there a similar approach with REST ? Can you give me example of "some data protocols/tools" ? Thanks

Comment: Since REST isn't really a standard but more a set of ideas its not really possible to do that kind of stuff, of course if you do REST with XML then you could create XML schemas and use those to generate representations in various languages. There is some work being done on JSON schemas but not sure how many actually use it. I think for example Google Protocol Buffers generates different language stubs and has got a DSL for describing the protocol (https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

Answer (score 0):

Well I suggest to send to the client a template of what they should display, on the client with js take advantage of js template frameworks, so you can tell to the client how can show them, dynamic... if they want to override them well... more job

We can call them Rest component oriented...

well suggestions :)

should works!